# How to handle $route params with Vue 2 SSR?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering, vue-ssr

The goal is to parse route params, find the item in the store (by param from the URL), and write some item's properties to the raw HTML with Vue 2 SSR:

```
<template>
    <div :class="$style.issue">
        <div>
            <div>{{ issue.title }}</div> <!-- not rendered by the server, only on the FE -->
            <a :href="issue.url">{{ issue.url }}</a> <!-- not rendered by the server, only on the FE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is how I'm trying to access the issue:

```
<script>
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex';
const { mapState } = createNamespacedHelpers('issues');

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            issues: state => state.issues,
        }),
        issue() {
            return this.issues.find((issue) => issue.id == this.$route.params.id);
            // I believe something is wrong with this.$route.params,
            // probably it's not there while doing SSR
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The store is ready, I can see it in the pagesource.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, nor what you tried with $route.